# Eventlistener "click" and show text in console.log doesnt work

Tags: javascript, console, click, element, event-listener

im trying to show text in the console.log when an image is clicked in the html. Now i get this error in the console in the browser: TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null.

**JS:**

```
function appear() {
    console.log("hello");
}


var button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("click", appear);
```

**HTML:**

```
<article id="button">
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `getElementById` can return nothing. You should add a check that it is returning a reference to the button:

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
if (button) {
  button.addEventListener("click", appear);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I still don't really understand what is happening.. It seems like im adding the check you said, but the console.log still doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would have a **Button** inside of your **Article** to apply your click event to, like this:

```
<article>
    <button id="button">Hey</button>
</article>
```

Your Javascript is correct, but only as long as **document.getElementById("button")** successfully finds the element with the ID "button".

When you open your browser console, you should be seeing "hello" when you click on the Button.